# How to execute tests with selenium webdriver while browser is minimized

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I try to run this program. it works fine with codes, however when I minimized the browser, error pop up. it seem that program is unable to find the button. is there anything that i can use to fix it. help

```js
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import os
import datetime
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox as msgbox

# Using Chrome to access web
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


master = Tk()
master.resizable(0, 0) #0 means false
genType = StringVar(master)       
options = ["1-Day Admission Only", "Audio Only"]
genType.set(options[0])


def optionChanged(var):
    if var == "1-Day Admission Only":
        met()
    elif var == "Audio Only":
        met()

genTypeMenu = OptionMenu(master, genType, *options, command=optionChanged)
        
def start():
    opt = genType.get()
          
    if opt == "1-Day Admission Only":


        
def met_one_day_admission():
    for i in range(int(qty.s.get())): 
        #do somethig here
        
b = Button(master, text="Start", width=20, command=start, fg="red")    
        
qty = entry_with_label("Quantity :", "100")


genTypeMenu.pack()
b.pack()
```

Comment: Please update your question with the specific error message you receive. You could also read the page [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you are unsure of the structure of the question.

Answer (score 6):

When you initiate the *Test Execution* through *Selenium*, normally the *Browser* is initiated in **maximized** *mode*. Now, to execute your program/script, **Selenium** needs the **focus** on the *Browser Client* which renders the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). When the *Test Execution* is *In Progress* if an user manually forcefully **minimizes** the browser, Selenium would loose the **focus** and an exception will be raised at any point of time which will halt the *Test Execution*.

You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium stops when browser is manually interrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174242/selenium-stops-when-browser-is-manually-interrupted)

### Why does minimized browser give element not found error

WebDriver drives the browser directly using the browser’s built in support for automation. WebDriver attempts to model the user experience and actions as closely as possible and makes direct calls to the browser using each browser’s native support for automation. Modeling the user experience requires certain design, technology and support for interacting with elements. These interactions and the features they support depends on the browser you are using. In short, most likely *Selenium* won't work if the browser is minimized since a user cannot interact with the webpage while the browser window is minimized.

You can find a detailed analysis from @JimEvans in [Selenium -Why does minimized browser give element not found error whereas max doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978327/selenium-why-does-minimized-browser-give-element-not-found-error-whereas-max-do)