# Selenium - Not able to find Button Element in HTML code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have just started learning Selenium and was playing around a bit trying to automate a search on the secondhand clothing website [vinted.fr](https://www.vinted.fr/vetements?search_text=adididas).

I was able to find all necessary Elements in the HTML code, except one: 
-The Button to change the "sort by" functionality to "newest". (
[This is a Screenshot of the Page including the Button I want to press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6UJ1.png))

Now I am wondering, what the Problem might be:
-Is it possible, that the button is not having a "button" tag in the HTML code. If yes how do I find and click this element?
-Am I just searching at wrong position?

Here is the HTML source code where I suggest the button element to be in:

[image: Screenshot of the HTML code]

Comment: Add the Html as text in your post and post your attempt, please.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element to set *sort by* functionality to *newest* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.pile li:nth-of-type(4) label"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='pile']//li[@class='pile__element'][last()]//label"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```