# Python Selenium - Checkbox Is Not Clicked With Explicit Wait

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

H, I am trying to click on the below checkbox.

```html
<thead class="ant-table-thead" xpath="1">
  <tr>
    <th class="ant-table-selection-column"><span class="ant-table-header-column"><div><span class="ant-table-column-title"><div class="ant-table-selection"><label class="ant-checkbox-wrapper"><span class="ant-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="ant-checkbox-input" value=""><span class="ant-checkbox-inner"></span></span>
      </label>
      </div>
      </span><span class="ant-table-column-sorter"></span></div>
      </span>
    </th>

 
  </tr>
</thead>
```

It gets clicked instantly only as follows:

```
Checkbox = "//thead/tr[1]/th[1]/span[1]/div[1]/span[1]/div[1]/label[1]/span[1]/input[1]"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(Checkbox).click()
```

However, when I try to add explicit wait, the checkbox doesn't get clicked

```
if WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, Checkbox))): driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                        Checkbox).click()
```

I have also tried `EC.visibility_of_element_located` but also doesn't work

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: What exactly is your problem?  Is the code failing because the checkbox is not clickable at first?

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code and at the documentation i think i figured out, i cannot reproduce to test but i will try to explain why isn't working:

From the [doc](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html):

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, Checkbox))

        driver.find_element_by_xpath(Checkbox).click()
    except TimeoutException as ex :
        
        *put here the "else" code, it will be execute if the wait ends with no Checkbox found so the WebDriver will Throw a TimeoutException*
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "thead.ant-table-thead input.ant-checkbox-input"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//thead[@class='ant-table-thead']//input[@class='ant-checkbox-input']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Im already doing that, but the element just doesn't get clicked when using webdriver wait