# Unable to access the element using Selenium , Python and ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Unable to Access the password by name tried this from a stackoverflow answer but still not working

```html
<input type="password" class="required valid" style="font-size: 14px; margin-top: 1em; padding: 0.3em !important; width: 100% !important; border-radius: 3px;" placeholder="password" name="password">
```

Code trials:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.NAME, passwordId))
).click()

driver.find_element_by_name(passwordId).send_keys(password)
```

Comment: what is there in passwordid

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [presence_of_element_located()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `NAME`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password'][placeholder='password']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password' and @placeholder='password']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)