# Selenium Checkbox Selection

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to use selenium to click on a checkbox, as is depicted in the HTML of the picture. The think is, the checkbox input tag is the same for all four options, and they are distinguished only through the `id="country_england" ...` . I'm not sure how I can write code to select the england box and click it. Any help appreciated.

HTML Code:

[image: HTML Code]

Answer (score 0):

**use xpath:**

```
 //b[@id="country_england"]/../input
```

### This finds the p tag that has that ID and then goes to the parent element and navigates back to input element

**you can also use:**

```
      //b[@id="country_england"]/preceding-sibling::input
```

### This finds the preceding element of p tag that has tag input

**Code would be :**

```
webD.get("https://icem.data-archive.ac.uk/#step1")

WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@value="1861"]'))).click()


WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '//b[@id = "country_england"]/preceding-sibling::input'))).click()
```

Comment: boxEng = webD.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@id="country_england"]::preceding-sibling/input')

boxEng.click()

Code still not successful.. Can you see a problem? Thank you for your help!!

Comment: `webD.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@id="country_england"]/preceding-sibling::input').click()`

Comment: @RyeRye updated the answer with code also

Comment: I really really appreciate your help!! But still no success.. Is there any additional info I could give you that would help? 
In any case I do see how this is the right direction, it feels so close...

Comment: Could you give the website URL ? Is the element inside iframe ?

Comment: https://icem.data-archive.ac.uk/#step1 this is the website. i successfully coded the years element. thank you!!

Comment: i miss read b as p thats why the locattor didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element. So to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and *preceding*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://icem.data-archive.ac.uk/#step1")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='1851']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//b[@class='ng-binding' and @id='country_england']//preceding::input[1]"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *preceding-sibling*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://icem.data-archive.ac.uk/#step1")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='1851']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//b[@class='ng-binding' and @id='country_england']//preceding-sibling::input[1]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: icem_data-archive]

---

### Update

[image: icem]

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your extensive response. Sadly still unsuccessful. If you wish to take a closer look, the website is the following: https://icem.data-archive.ac.uk/#step1
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Could you elaborate the suggestion? Not sure how to implement it. But I don't think I can... I'll sleep on it and have a look with fresh eyes tomorrow. Thank you again, if you have any other ideas i'd love to try them out :)

Comment: @RyeRye Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Tired eyes indeed... Yes I was able to, as the code for the input has a unique value to identify each checkbox in the years. I used classic xpath and click combo. Thank you! Will try out now :)

Comment: PDHide suggested the following code: WebDriverWait(webD, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '//b[@id = "country_england"]/preceding-sibling::input'))).click()

and it was successful. Thank you very much for your help :) I can finally say... good night!