# Clicking a button which is inside another element Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

HTML snapshot:

[image]

Hi I want press the button labelled log in on this page, the html for the button is as follows:

```
<button class="">Log In</button>
```

the problem is there is multiple log in buttons on the same page with this code so I want to specify this button by using the id of the container the button is in:

```
<li id  = 'bs-bk-PP" class = "_2t6uLu"
```

How do I find and click the log in button using these properties.
Thanks

Comment: Note: I have added a screenshot of how the code appears when I inspect element

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Log In** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@id='bs-bk-PP']//button[@class and text()='Log In']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@id='bs-bk-PP']//button[@class and text()='Log In']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks but this selects the wrong log in button on the page. How do I include the id for the correct container as per my initial question ?

Comment: @Eglantine46 Can you update the question with the text based complete HTML of the element including it;s parent elements?

Comment: Can you see the screenshot of the html code in the question? I am unable to select all the html code as it is contained inside different Divs, is it possible to first select the element using the ID = bs-bk-PP then from that element click the log in button using "//button[@class and text()='Log In']" as you mentioned above?

Comment: @Eglantine46 Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status