# XPath for element which contains non unique nested element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Wondering is anybody can help me finding an xpath for the following element on a page

I am creating a test  for the following question - I have been able to find an xpath for the Q1 is registered user portion but I would like to find an xpath which selects is reigstered user and also the Yes answer

[image]

Below is the HTML of the element

```
<div ng-show="resultsVm.eligibilityResults.questionAnswerPairs.length &amp;&amp; doesBusinessExist" class="row show-grid" ng-repeat="eligibilityResult in resultsVm.eligibilityResults.questionAnswerPairs">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <label>
                Q1. Is Registered User?
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ng-class="{
              'glyphicon-ok' : (eligibilityResult.answer.answerCode == 'Y')
              , 'glyphicon-remove' : (eligibilityResult.answer.answerCode == 'N')
              , 'glyphicon-flag' : (eligibilityResult.answer.answerCode == 'O')
              }" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Yes
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Which element you'd like to select? Also share your current XPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use following xpaths:

To get question:

```
//label[contains(text(),"Q1. Is Registered User?")]
```

To get answer of specific question:

```
//label[contains(text(),"User")]/ancestor::div[@class="row show-grid"]//*[text()[contains(.,"Yes") or contains(.,"No")]]
```

### Here we are getting the parent of the question and then go back to the answer

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Yes** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *Java* and `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(., 'Is Registered User')]//following::div[./span[contains(@ng-class, 'answerCode')]]")).click();
  ```
- Using *Python* and `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[contains(., 'Is Registered User')]//following::div[./span[contains(@ng-class, 'answerCode')]]").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *Java* and `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[contains(., 'Is Registered User')]//following::div[./span[contains(@ng-class, 'answerCode')]]"))).click();
  ```
- Using *Python* and `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[contains(., 'Is Registered User')]//following::div[./span[contains(@ng-class, 'answerCode')]]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: For *Python* clients you have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```