# Automate web driver to visit the next page page using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation, webdriverwait

I am trying to automate going to the next product list in the following website.

https://munnalaldawasaz.in/categories/essential-oils

I don't see any change in the url while visiting the next page.

I have attached an image for element that is to be clicked.

Image:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add your code to your answer

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element <kbd>></kbd> you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//article/div[@class='toolbar']//div[@class='pages']//ul[@class='pagination']//a[text()='Last']//preceding::li[1]/a").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//article/div[@class='toolbar']//div[@class='pages']//ul[@class='pagination']//a[text()='Last']//preceding::li[1]/a"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```