# How to click <a class href > link question using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, linktext

Hi I am new to Selenium Python Webdriver. Trying to click the link `Abc` by using  `find_element_by_link_text` which didn't work ,

```
<a class="favorite-link " href="https://onesource.passporthealth.com/_members/query/osusf/Default.aspx?dlpvid=0000&amp;sid=-111111111">Abc</a>
```

I will appreciate the help. Any idea how to use xpath for this case?

```
          <div id="favCol1" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="padding: 2px; margin: 0px;">
                                    <div id="favId2861214" class="elig-item">
                                        <div title="Remove payer from favorites list" class="delete-favorite" data-itemname="Aetna" data-favid="2861214" data-dsid="28" data-lobid="1"></div>
                                        <a class="favorite-link " href="https://onesource.passporthealth.com/_members/query/osusf/Default.aspx?dlpvid=1111&amp;sid=-000000">Abc</a>
                                        <span class="side-text"></span>
                                    </div>

                                    
                                    <div id="favId2869169" class="elig-item">
                                        <div title="Remove payer from favorites list" class="delete-favorite" data-itemname="CIGNA" data-favid="2869169" data-dsid="317" data-lobid="1"></div>
                                        <a class="favorite-link " href="https://onesource.passporthealth.com/_members/query/osusf/Default.aspx?dlpvid=0000&amp;sid=-11111133323">efg</a>
                                        <span class="side-text"></span>
                                    </div>

                                    
                                    <div id="favId2861157" class="elig-item">
                                        <div title="Remove payer from favorites list" class="delete-favorite" data-itemname="Florida Blue" data-favid="2861157" data-dsid="35" data-lobid="1"></div>
                                        <a class="favorite-link " href="https://onesource.passporthealth.com/_members/query/osusf/Default.aspx?dlpvid=2323&amp;sid=-1111111">xyz</a>
                                        <span class="side-text"></span>
                                    </div>

                                    
                                    <div id="favId2861963" class="elig-item">
                                        <div title="Remove payer from favorites list" class="delete-favorite" data-itemname="Humana" data-favid="2861963" data-dsid="82" data-lobid="1"></div>
                                        <a class="favorite-link " href="https://onesource.passporthealth.com/_members/query/osusf/Default.aspx?dlpvid=1233&amp;sid=-000021212">HIJ</a>
                                        <span class="side-text"></span>
                                    </div>                             
                                </div>
```

Tried:

```
.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'favorite-link') and contains(text(), 'Abc')]/a").click()
```

update:
The whole block was embedded in an iFrame. That's why I couldn't access. Had to switch to that frame.

Comment: Any particular problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Abc** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Abc")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='elig-item']//a[@class='favorite-link ' and text()='Abc']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Abc"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='elig-item']//a[@class='favorite-link ' and text()='Abc']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: It still can't find the element. Also tried the Webdriverwait. I keep getting Timeout. Increased the time. No success yet! This is weird, should have worked by now. Thanks though.

Comment: I think the whole block is embedded in an iFrame. That's why I couldn't access

Answer (score 2):

```
 driver.find_element_by_link_text("Abc").click()
```

Just click the tag with the link text Abc.

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Abc']").click()
```

Comment: I tried that. But does not work. I guess because there is also class="favorite-link " . Probably i will have to use xpath. But don't know how to use it.

Comment: You can just grab the xpath from the developer console by inspecting it and right click copy xpath.

Comment: You can just need to add div[@id='']/ to the above in the xpath for it to work.

Comment: I have also tried that the xpath i copied was ```browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="favId2861963"]/a').click()``` , but didn't work. says element wasn't found. Thanks though!

Comment: That block is embedded in an iFrame. That's why I couldn't access. Had to switch to that frame.