# Trouble selecting google one box tab in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, python-webbrowser

going to `https://www.google.com/search?q=tennis` a google one box comes up for scores, I'm trying to click on the tabs and (Women's Singles, Men's Doubles etc) and having no luck. I've tried all methods, xpath, classname, partial link text, css selector.

[image]

any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element, so ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Clicking *Women's Singles*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=tennis')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@jsslot]//span//span[contains(., 'Women') and contains(., 'Singles')]"))).click()
  ```
- Clicking *Men's Doubles*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=tennis')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@jsslot]//span//span[contains(., 'Men') and contains(., 'Doubles')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much! How come chrome's "Copy xPath" doesn't work? Out of interest

Answer (score 0):

I always use this method to set the XPath in Selenium based Python projects.

1. Click F12 after opening the link
2. In Elements, Click Ctrl + F. Now search some unique term in the page. I gave Men's Singles and this snippet came up.

```
<div class="SVWlSe FZzi2e" jsslot="">
    <span jsslot="">
       <div aria-controls="_dtAkYIqaMLraz7sPnrW54A435_0" 
            id="_dtAkYIqaMLraz7sPnrW54A434_0">
            <span>
                <span>Men's Singles</span>
             </span>
       </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

3. Now right-click the snippet to get the XPath format or use the XPath Syntax. Here, the XPath is //div[@class='SVWlSe FZzi2e']. To find whether the attribute value is unique, I would suggest you to search within elements again with the value.

Notice that I used the class attribute instead of the aria-controls and id attributes since id and aria-controls changed over time.