# selenium, python - WebDriverWait times out 60% of the time no matter what I set the delay to

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Traceback

```
09:32:01 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mike/projects/work/blacklight/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 975, in perform_job
    rv = job.perform()
  File "/home/mike/projects/work/blacklight/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 696, in perform
    self._result = self._execute()
  File "/home/mike/projects/work/blacklight/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 719, in _execute
    return self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "./sba_scraper/scrape.py", line 69, in scrape
    any_minority_owned_checkbox = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
  File "/home/mike/projects/work/blacklight/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Code

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options)
url = 'https://web.sba.gov/pro-net/search/dsp_dsbs.cfm'
driver.get(url)
delay = 60
checkbox = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'EltCbtMin')))
```

Whether I set the delay to 3 or 10 or 60, Most of the time I get the exception above, that it timed out before it could find the element. Obviously it works 40% of the time though. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) associated with text as **Any Minority Owned** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://web.sba.gov/pro-net/search/dsp_dsbs.cfm')
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#EltCbtMin[aria-labelledby='LabCbtMin']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://web.sba.gov/pro-net/search/dsp_dsbs.cfm')
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='EltCbtMin' and @aria-labelledby='LabCbtMin']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://web.sba.gov/pro-net/search/dsp_dsbs.cfm')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#EltCbtMin[aria-labelledby='LabCbtMin']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://web.sba.gov/pro-net/search/dsp_dsbs.cfm')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='EltCbtMin' and @aria-labelledby='LabCbtMin']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: web_sba_gov]