# Finding element by custom button attribute using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

On a webpage, I have a button element with various attributes.

```
<button class="alert-area rj-button--plain ng-binding" ng-click="forceStructSync()" bs-tooltip="" data-original-title="This runs a structure sync, and makes sure our warehouse is aware of any new tables you've added to your database recently." data-placement="right" button-text="Check for new tables and columns"> <span class="rj-icon--refresh"></span> Check for new tables and columns </button>
```

I have tried with selenium with different forms of syntax to select and click the element using its `button-text` attribute, but am unsure where the error is coming from.  It is definitely **not** a timing issue, in other words, the page is loaded when the find command is executed.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
import time


driver.get ('https://mywebsite.com')
#time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".button[button-text='Check for new tables and columns']").click()
```

I have also tried the camel case `buttonText` and `button_text` in place `button-text`, but this throws the same error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to lo
cate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".button[button-text='Check for new tabl
es and columns']"}
```

Any suggestions on what might be the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.alert-area.rj-button--plain.ng-binding[ng-click^='forceStructSync'][data-original-title^='This runs a structure sync']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='alert-area rj-button--plain ng-binding' and starts-with(@ng-click, 'forceStructSync')][contains(., 'Check for new tables and columns')]").click()
  ```

---

The desired element is a dynamic element, so ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.alert-area.rj-button--plain.ng-binding[ng-click^='forceStructSync'][data-original-title^='This runs a structure sync']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='alert-area rj-button--plain ng-binding' and starts-with(@ng-click, 'forceStructSync')][contains(., 'Check for new tables and columns')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer was not to include the period before button so this worked:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[button-text='Check for new tables and columns']").click()
```

Comment: The `.` indicates a class. In this case, BUTTON is a tag and not a class. That's why removing the `.` fixed this locator.