# Selenium Webdriver Python clicking on a link to open yjs based form as a popup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Selenium WebDriver Python

Please refer to the image below:

[image]

In this image we have a link which on click will open popup window to enter data:
But the problem is that this link is not clickable with selenium `WebDriver`.
What I have tried?

- Adding wait by using `WebDriverWait` and then clicking element.
- (`data-yjs-datasource-url="/legals/add"`) copying Url from this attribute and appending it to the base url. This opens the add liability page in new windows but on new page "Save" button is not available, like you can write data in the form but there is no way to save those changes

I need help on how to click on this button and open a popup in the same window and then enter the data.
Is there any way through which I can retrieve the `yjs` based form as a popup in same window?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please don't attach your code as picture

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **save** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-right > li > a[data-yjs-datasource-url='/legals/add']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right']/li[@class]/a[@data-yjs-datasource-url='/legals/add']").click()
  ```

The desired element is a dynamic element, so ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.signin-btn.sbLoginBtn > span.btf-text"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right']/li[@class]/a[@data-yjs-datasource-url='/legals/add']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```