# How to select option from datalist after typing using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to select an option from datalist using selenium. First, send the option name from keys, and after send an arrow down to select it. Everything goes well until send ENTER key, it does not take any action. I must press down and enter keys to make the submit button clickable and can't modify the HTML code

I have tried

- Send the whole name to the input
- Send DOWN and ENTER keys together
- Send RETURN Key

This is the datalist HTML code

```
...
<input _ngcontent-njw-c0="" list="salesmans" placeholder="Selecciona Cliente o Vendedor" style="width: 100%;border: none;">
<datalist _ngcontent-njw-c0="" id="salesmans">
<option _ngcontent-njw-c0="" value="Vendedor Venta" ng-reflect-value="Vendedor Venta"></option>
<option _ngcontent-njw-c0="" value="juan peña hjvgvghghc" ng-reflect-value="juan peña hjvgvghghc"></option>
...
```

My python code

```
...
user_selector = WebDriverWait(self.loader.chrome_driver, con.TIME_LIMIT).until(
                ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@placeholder="Selecciona Cliente o Vendedor"]')))

user_selector.send_keys(user_auth_data[2])
user_selector.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
...
```

Element image:

[image: The code just work until send down key]

Answer (score 1):

To select the option from datalist with text as **Vendedor Venta** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) instead of sending `DOWN` and `ENTER` keys together as the desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder="Selecciona Cliente o Vendedor"]"))).send_keys(user_auth_data[2])
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "option[value='Vendedor Venta'][ng-reflect-value='Vendedor Venta']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder="Selecciona Cliente o Vendedor"]"))).send_keys(user_auth_data[2])
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//option[@value='Vendedor Venta' and @ng-reflect-value='Vendedor Venta']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I tried to implement that solution however I got the error message: javascript error: option element is not in a select. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below options.

1. Try sending the whole name to the input and try first manually pressing the 'ENTER' or 'TAB' button. ( if any of this works and then you can send that key in your code after entering the whole name)
2. Try sending the whole name to the input and then find the XPath of the option that you want to select. Also please note that the XPath of an option (that you want to select) can be different than the original once, once you send the whole name. so plz consider that.

I was facing a similar issue and the second option worked for me, however, I did it in [C#](https://www.dotnetguide.com/introduction-to-dot-net-framework/)  and not in Python.

Thanks,

[John](https://www.dotnetguide.com/garbage-collection-in-c/)