# Click a button that pops up a window

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

URL:
https://efun.toronto.ca/torontofun/Activities/ActivitiesCourseDetails.asp?aid=18830&cid=6455687

Clicking the "Add" button generates a pop-up window where you need to enter your credentials. I've tried different ways of clicking the button with Selenium/Python to produce the popup window but nothing seems to works.

Snippet of my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import xpath
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get('https://efun.toronto.ca/torontofun/Activities/ActivitiesCourseDetails.asp?aid=18830&cid=6455687')

add_buttom_try1 = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "Add"))).click()

add_buttom_try2 = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-state-active ui-corner-all link-button ajax-request from-full-page focus-child need-focus-pageobject")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: [strategies to locate elements on a page](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Here are some ways to find the "Add" button:

**Using XPATH:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://efun.toronto.ca/torontofun/Activities/ActivitiesCourseDetails.asp?aid=18830&cid=6455687')

add_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'Add')]")
add_button[0].click()
```

**Using CSS_SELECTOR:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://efun.toronto.ca/torontofun/Activities/ActivitiesCourseDetails.asp?aid=18830&cid=6455687')

add_button = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.ui-state-active')
add_button[2].click()
```

**USING LINK_TEXT:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://efun.toronto.ca/torontofun/Activities/ActivitiesCourseDetails.asp?aid=18830&cid=6455687')

add_button = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Add')
add_button.click()
```

Sometimes your code can execute before the "button" is clickable.  When this happens an error will be thrown.  Adding a WebDriverWait statement is a good practice when looking for an element that is clickable.

ref: [selenium wait statements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://efun.toronto.ca/torontofun/Activities/ActivitiesCourseDetails.asp?aid=18830&cid=6455687')

# one method
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
add_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Add")))
add_button.click()

# another method
# wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
# wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Add"))).click()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element <kbd>Add</kbd> you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://efun.toronto.ca/torontofun/Activities/ActivitiesCourseDetails.asp?aid=18830&cid=6455687")
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Add To My Cart'] > span").click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://efun.toronto.ca/torontofun/Activities/ActivitiesCourseDetails.asp?aid=18830&cid=6455687")     
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Add']").click()
  ```

---

The desired element is a [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) enabled element, so ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://efun.toronto.ca/torontofun/Activities/ActivitiesCourseDetails.asp?aid=18830&cid=6455687")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Add To My Cart'] > span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://efun.toronto.ca/torontofun/Activities/ActivitiesCourseDetails.asp?aid=18830&cid=6455687")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Add']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: add]