# Selenium(PYTHON) ng-click issue

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have been stuck on this issue, where no matter how i write out the navigation to the specific element, using .click() wont work, the element 100% loads in before the click is fired(this i know because i can manually click it), but it wont actually click, is there something about ng-click that needs specification or what, but hopefully i can atleast get some closure as to why this element wont be clicked

```
<div class="item-card-thumb-container" ng-click="root.onItemCardClick(userAsset)">
```

is there any possible way to click this element without specifically finding that element and adding .click() to it, because it doesn't seem to work, I understand its too vague, but also maybe the element isn't clickable unless the mouse hovers over the element, cause it is a UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element element, so ideally to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.item-card-thumb-container[ng-click^='onItemCardClick']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='item-card-thumb-container' and contains(@ng-click, 'onItemCardClick')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```