# Code can not locate elements on switched popup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I can not click on Agree button on pop iframe. I tested multiple methods of elements and selenium library. The code returns error:

> "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":"[id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]"}   (Session
> info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)"

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://skelbiu.lt")
driver.implicitly_wait ( 30 )
driver.maximize_window ()
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"lsgetframe")))

try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']").click()
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print("e 1", e)
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException) as e:
    print("e 2", e)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='onetrust-button-group']/button").click()
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print("e 3", e)
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='onetrust-button-group']/button"))).click()
except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException) as e:
    print("e 4", e)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[2]/div/button").click()
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print("e 5", e)
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[2]/div/button"))).click()
except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException) as e:
    print("e 6", e)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print("e 7", e)
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException) as e:
    print("e 8", e)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print("e 9", e)
time.sleep(5)
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException) as e:
    print("e 10", e)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click()
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print("e 11", e)
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]'))).click()
except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException) as e:
    print("e 12", e)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[10]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/button[1]').click()
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print("e 13", e)
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[10]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/button[1]'))).click()
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print("e 14", e)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The element <kbd>Sutinku</kbd> isn't within any `<iframe>` as such. But the element is a dynamic element, so ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.skelbiu.lt/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.skelbiu.lt/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Sutinku']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: You suggested code with css selector has worked. Iframe element in html misleaded. I tested previously multiple methods with recorded by Katalon Recorder without prior switch to iframe. Thanks for help.