# Selenium chromedriver cannot click href link

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am writing a script to automate data collection and was having trouble clicking a link. The website is behind a login, but I navigated that successfully. I ran into problems when trying to navigate to the download page. This is in python using chrome webdriver.

I have tried using:

```
find_element_by_partial_link_text('stuff').click()
find_element_by_xpath('stuff').click()
#and a few others
```

I get iterations of following message when I try a few of the selector statements.

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"download"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.182)
```

Html source I'm trying to use is:

```
<a routerlink="/download" title="Download" href="/itron-mvweb/download"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-download"></i><span class="menu-item-parent">Download</span></a>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What kinds of problems? Please see [ask].

Comment: @Seth Yep, sorry. Updated now.

Comment: Seems to be caused by a typo. `Download` needs to be capitalized (due to case-sensitivity).

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a typo. `Download` is case-sensitive, make sure you capitalize the `D`!

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Download** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Download'][href='/itron-mvweb/download'] span.menu-item-parent").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Download' and @href='/itron-mvweb/download']//span[@class='menu-item-parent' and text()='Download']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Download'][href='/itron-mvweb/download'] span.menu-item-parent"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Download' and @href='/itron-mvweb/download']//span[@class='menu-item-parent' and text()='Download']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)