# How do I select the an element without an ID/text_link/name in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, linktext

[HTML of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61jjd.png)

The HTML code of the element I want to select:

```
   <a href="../s-reminderNotice.asp?fname=b%2D3c%2DpLessonBooking%2Easp%3Flimit%3Dpl" class="sidelinkbold" 
   target="mainFrame" 
   onmouseover=" window.status='Practical Training Booking'; 
   return true" onmouseout="window.status=' ';
   return true">Booking without Fixed Instructor</a>
```

I would like to select the element of this "Booking without Fixed Instructor" ; however there isn't an ID/link_text/name for this element. How can I direct the site to the HREF. Is there a way to use xpath to locate it , the element is in the column on the left of the website so there are many other elements of the same class. (see pic.)

I tried this and it returned:

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'
```

Code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='THE LINK']")).click();
```

SOLVED; ELEMENT WAS IN AN IFRAME ; HAD TO SWITCH FRAME TO ACCESS ELEMENT

Comment: could you share site link and elaborate question in detail? I will happy to help you

Comment: You would need my credentials to log into the website ; which I am unable to provide. I could add you on discord and share my screen if that's possible

Comment: sure... you can give link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Booking without Fixed Instructor** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `link_text`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Booking without Fixed Instructor")
  ```
- Using `partial_link_text`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Booking without Fixed Instructor").click()
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.sidelinkbold[href*='s-reminderNotice']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='sidelinkbold' and contains(@href, 's-reminderNotice')][contains(., 'Booking without Fixed Instructor')]").click()
  ```

---

The desired element is a dynamic element, so ideally to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Booking without Fixed Instructor"))).click()
  ```
- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Booking without Fixed Instructor"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.sidelinkbold[href*='s-reminderNotice']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='sidelinkbold' and contains(@href, 's-reminderNotice')][contains(., 'Booking without Fixed Instructor')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: This is perfect however I have tried all the methods but still get NoSuchElementException ;  I have already added the wait buffer to allow the website to load? and reason this might still occur

Comment: I have figured it out ; apparently it was under an iframe , thus i had to switch the frame to access the element

Comment: @gabethechef Updated the answer with references to **NoSuchElementException**

Answer (score 1):

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'
```

you are using python so driver dowsn't have findElemnt method , it is find_Element

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html?highlight=webdriver%20class#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_class_name

```
use:

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//a[contains(string(),'Booking without Fixed Instructor')]")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this xpath:

```
//a[text()[contains(.,'Booking without Fixed Instructor')]]
```