# Selenium can't find the div element to click

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium to automate some tasks with webdriver.

Turns out I can't find a div to click on, selenium just can't find it.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

**HTML :**

```
<div aria-controls="leftAdvPnl_body" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" class="rich-stglpanel-header " id="leftAdvPnl_header" onclick="SimpleTogglePanelManager.toggleOnClient(event,'leftAdvPnl');" onkeypress="return keypressclickhandle(event);" role="link" tabindex="0"><div aria-hidden="true" class="rich-stglpanel-marker"><div class="rich-stglpnl-marker" aria-hidden="true" id="leftAdvPnl_switch_on" style="display: none">«</div><div class="rich-stglpnl-marker" aria-hidden="true" id="leftAdvPnl_switch_off">»</div></div><span id="leftAdvPnl_header_label">Pesquisar</span><span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

Code phyton:

```
while len(navegador.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="leftAdvPnl_header"]')) < 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Procurando formulário do processo")

link=navegador.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="leftAdvPnl_header"]")
link.click()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please try to use `find_element_by_css_selector` instead of the `find_element_by_xpath` and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I tried:
while len(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('span#id_leftAdvPnl_header_label')) < 1:
time.sleep(1)
print("Looking for process form")

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 nested double quotes, instead of `"//*[@id="leftAdvPnl_header"]"` use `'//*[@id="leftAdvPnl_header"]'`

Comment: No influence.
Selenium cannot find this div. It has no code error.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the link to the site?

Comment: I would like to, but it's an application that can only be accessed by digital certificate.
Is there any way to do this while preserving personal data?

Comment: @DiogoNature Welcome to the life of automation, sometimes websites just want to be difficult. We are building an automation tool called Roboteur which will allow you to automate testing processes without writing a single line of code. Its an automation tool, so there is way more to do with it than just automating test cases. Check it out. https://spacepencil.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for an element to be clickable, so try:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="leftAdvPnl_header"]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//div[@id='leftAdvPnl_header']
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If we have 1/1 matching node, Please make sure that :

1. This div is not under an iframe.
2. This div is not under a shadow-root.
3. You should not be on new tab/windows launched by selenium.

**Code :**

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(navegador, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='leftAdvPnl_header']"))).click()
    print("Clicked on web element")
except:
    pass
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Updated :**

`CSS` are far more better locator than `XPath`, please try the below one :

```
div[onclick^='SimpleTogglePanelManager.toggleOnClient'][onclick*='(event,'][onclick*='leftAdvPnl']
```

Same way to check if we have 1/1 matching node or not.

To click, there are 4 ways in Selenium.

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[onclick^='SimpleTogglePanelManager.toggleOnClient'][onclick*='(event,'][onclick*='leftAdvPnl']").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[onclick^='SimpleTogglePanelManager.toggleOnClient'][onclick*='(event,'][onclick*='leftAdvPnl']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3:**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[onclick^='SimpleTogglePanelManager.toggleOnClient'][onclick*='(event,'][onclick*='leftAdvPnl']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[onclick^='SimpleTogglePanelManager.toggleOnClient'][onclick*='(event,'][onclick*='leftAdvPnl']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Yes, xpatch is found.


1. There is only 1 iframe on the page, but it is not inside this element:


<iframe src="/primeirograu/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/images/spacer.gif" id="formLocCaix:decosuggestProcessoAdvogadoProc:sugsuggestProcessoAdvogadoProc_iframe" style="position:absolute;display:none;z-index:200;"></iframe>


2. I need to study about it, I can't identify if it exists or not.


3. No, it's not a new tab.


Apparently this platform was built with Jboss.

Comment: If xpath is unique, the you should try out my solution.. it should work. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I would very much like to have worked out, but no.

Is it something related to the onclick="SimpleTogglePanelManager.toggleOnClient(event,'leftAdvPnl');" ?

Comment: Please see updated section above, I hope that will work.

Comment: I tested all 4 codes and nothing, there must be something hiding this div, impossible.

Log error: https://paste-bin.xyz/10678

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as *`Pesquisar`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.rich-stglpanel-header#leftAdvPnl_header span#leftAdvPnl_header_label").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Pesquisar' and @id='leftAdvPnl_header_label']").click()
  ```

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.rich-stglpanel-header#leftAdvPnl_header span#leftAdvPnl_header_label"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Pesquisar' and @id='leftAdvPnl_header_label']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```