# Cant click option in options wrapper - python selenium

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I am having trouble selecting an option in popup-bubble (sorry I am not quite sure how to determine what type of popup it is)
I dont really mind what option I choose, I just need to click one of them.
This is how it looks in code:

```
<div data-v-d4e6e290="" class="f_input-optionsWrapper js_optionsWrapper" style=""><div data-v-d4e6e290="" class="f_input-options"><div data-v-d4e6e290="" class="f_input-header js_header">Oslovení</div> <div data-v-d4e6e290="" class="f_input-options-content"><div class="f_customScroll" data-v-d4e6e290="" style="max-height: 883px;"><div data-v-68c7351e="" class="f_input-option"><div data-v-68c7351e="" data-testid="Pan" class="f_input-option-text xh-highlight">
        Pan
    </div></div><div data-v-68c7351e="" class="f_input-option"><div data-v-68c7351e="" data-testid="Paní" class="f_input-option-text">
        Paní
    </div></div></div> <div data-v-d4e6e290="" class="f_input-footer js_footer"><!----> <span data-v-d4e6e290="" class="f_button f_button--common f_button_set--small">Potvrdit</span></div></div></div></div>
```

[image: This is the popup box]

I tried to locate the elements multiple ways, the first problem is that it always detects two results. The popup is to choose the sex of the traveler and I have two travelers so my guess is it detects the second popup for second traveler as well.

My tries to locate:

```
volbaOsloveni = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='f_input-optionsWrapper js_optionsWrapper'] //*[@class='f_input-option-text']")
volbaOsloveni2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@data-testid='Pan']")
volbaOsloveni3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='f_customScroll'] //*[@data-testid='Pan']")
```

All of these gets me two results which I guess should work. Whenever I try to click the element selenium either says that it didnt locate the element or it just passes it acting as it already clicked the element and the script continues.

Click tries:

```
volbaOsloveni[0].click()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", volbaOsloveni3)
volbaOsloveni2[1].click()
```

I tried the find_elementS method so I am getting more of the results so that is why I tried to click on the first element with [0] and so on.
Neither the execute_script or the click() does the job and I am kinda desperate what to do now.

Can anyone help me with that please? Would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to click on `Pan` or `Paní`

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//div[@data-testid='Paní']
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If we have 1/1 matching node, Please use any one the mentioned code below to make a click :

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='Paní']").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='Paní']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='Paní']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='Paní']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Also, if you still see 2 elements for the XPath

```
//div[@data-testid='Paní']
```

please use XPath indexing :

```
(//div[@data-testid='Paní'])[2]
```

to filter out the nodes based on index.

Comment: Thanks, the indexing of xpath path solved the isssue. Although I thought whenever I use find_elements() method and then index the element that it should work in the same way but appearently not.
The biggest problem was that the xpath path was always locating 2 elements so it finally works. Thank you for help!

Comment: @KDK : Glad we could solve this. But I would like to highlight that XPath indexing is not the optimum solution, and it should be last resort if none of the XPath works. Anyway cheers !

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element with text as *`Pan`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.f_input-options div.f_input-options-content div[data-testid='Pan']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='f_input-options']//div[@class='f_input-options-content']//div[@data-testid='Pan']").click()
  ```

---

The desired element is a dynamic element, so ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.f_input-options div.f_input-options-content div[data-testid='Pan']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='f_input-options']//div[@class='f_input-options-content']//div[@data-testid='Pan']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this didnt solve the problem. Waiting for the element to be clickable makes sense, but now the script just continued as if selenium clicked the element but in reality it didnt choose anything. I will prolly need to index the xpath as the second comment suggests since there are two elements with the same xpath.