# Scrape amazon url image/picture in python with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I just need help for scrape Amazon url of image/picture on product page (first image, big size in screen), in python with selenium.
For example, this product:
https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B07CG3HFPV/ref=cm_sw_r_fm_api_glt_i_2RB9QBPTQXWJ7PQQ16MZ?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1

[image]

Here is the part of source code web page:
[image]

I need to **scrape** url image with tag "src".

Anyone know how to **scrape** this please?
Actually, I have this script part, but don't work:

```
url = https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B07CG3HFPV/ref=cm_sw_r_fm_api_glt_i_2RB9QBPTQXWJ7PQQ16MZ?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1

options = Options()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
import time
time.sleep(2)

actions = ActionChains(driver)

link_img = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("img").get_attribute("src")
```

Thanks for help

Comment: You need to find a pattern for that image location in the dom, or the class names or the id, or ... no easy way around it. Your code obviously does not work because you can be sure there is more than one image on that page.

Comment: You can make a way, or an example for to scrap this url please? I've tested more xpath, css selector, tag, but no way out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To scrape the amazon url of image/picture on product page (first image, big size in screen), in python with selenium you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`visibility_of_element_located()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.a-list-item>span.a-declarative>div.imgTagWrapper>img.a-dynamic-image"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='a-list-item']/span[@class='a-declarative']/div[@class='imgTagWrapper']/img[@class='a-dynamic-image']"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```