# How to interact with button based on text using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to click buttons based on their text (using selenium). e.g., for the following HTML tag:

```
<span class="MuiTab-wrapper jss483">Options</span>
```

I've tried:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Options')]").click()
```

However, Selenium can't find any element with the text: "***Options***".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Options')]
```

or

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Options')]
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

There are 4 ways to click in Selenium.

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Options')]").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Options')]"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Options')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Options')]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Also, `find_elements` returns a list, change that to `find_element` you should be good to go ahead.

or else use list index to point web element.

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Options')]")
elems[0].click()
```

This is not recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `find_elements_by_xpath` method. It will give you a list of web elements, not a single web element. So you can not apply `.click()` on the result of

```py
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Options')]")
```

You should use `find_element_by_xpath` instead so your code will be

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Options')]").click()
```

or clicking on the first result (or any other) from the web elements list returner, as following

```py
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Options')]")[0].click()
```

Also possibly you need to add some delay / wait to let the element be loaded before accessing it.
Or maybe you need to scroll that element into the view.
Or maybe the element is inside an iframe...

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as *`Options`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'MuiTab-wrapper') and contains(., 'Options')]").click()
  ```

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element, so ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'MuiTab-wrapper') and contains(., 'Options')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```