# How to simulate a clicking at this on/off button in python selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pseudo-element

I am trying to write a selenium code to simulate a switch on/off action.

This is the UI of that application and its actual source code under:

[image]

As we can see the **label::before** is mapped to "**on**" action, and **label::after** is for "**off**".

Following is my current python code that is not able to make such click.

```
def turnoff_byPlanCapacity(self):
    try:
        by_Plan_Capacity     =  "//div[contains(text(), 'Modem1 Settings')]/following-sibling:div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/label"
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, by_Plan_Capacity))).click()
    except Exception as e:
        self.logger.info(e)
        raise
```

Does anyone know a solution for it ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

To simulate clicking on the **On** / **Off** button you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for*='byPlanCapacity']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[starts-with(@for, 'byPlanCapacity')]").click()
  ```

The desired element is a dynamic element, so ideally to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for*='byPlanCapacity']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[starts-with(@for, 'byPlanCapacity')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Your effective code block will be:

```
def turnoff_byPlanCapacity(self):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[starts-with(@for, 'byPlanCapacity')]"))).click()
    except Exception as e:
        self.logger.info(e)
    raise
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think the blocking issue is the pseudo code on that page, that how to have selenium to handle them ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this xpath

```
//input[starts-with(@id,'byPlanCapacity') and @type='checkbox']//following-sibling::label
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If we have unique entry in HTMLDOM, then

```
def turnoff_byPlanCapacity(self):
    try:
        by_Plan_Capacity = "//input[starts-with(@id,'byPlanCa[acity') and @type='checkbox']//following-sibling::label"
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, by_Plan_Capacity))).click()
    except Exception as e:
        self.logger.info(e)
        raise
```

Note that I am using `element_to_be_clickable` instead of `presence_of_element_located`

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  As you suggested XPATH value,  I did get 1:1 match when checking it directly on the browser. But somehow, it is for the full button, not the "on" or "off" part, and I don't see the clicking happens during my execution time.   "::before" is so called javascript, how should I deal with that ?