# ActionChains double_click() method does not performs the double click using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action, double-click

I have the following web page

[image: webpage].

I'm trying to double click the "Blocked_IPs" text.

This is the code that interacts with it:

```
blocked_ips = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[contains(.,"Blocked_IPs")]')
print(len(blocked_ips), blocked_ips)
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.double_click(blocked_ips[0])
```

Problem is, it just doesn't seem to double click it. When I do it manually, it works. When I execute the code, it doesn't. There's only one occurance of the word "Blocked_IPs". This is the output in the terminal:

```
1 [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="82b277a5f85cbb202f5cd57c0b800f3b", element="530b1a15-a190-401c-8495-921777f8fa84")>]
```

Does anyone happen to know why it's not working? How can I test it? Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add *`perform()`* to make all the *ActionChains* happen as follows:

```
action.double_click(blocked_ips[0]).perform()
```

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
ActionChains(driver).double_click(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(.,"Blocked_IPs")]")))).perform()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```