# How to move the Mouse 9 pixels up from an element using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, action, webdriverwait, mousemove

I have a problem. I need to move the mouse to an element, and then raise the mouse 9 pixels up from this element.

```
classic = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"surf-text")  
nadclassiknav = webdriver.ActionChains(browser).move_by_offset(0, -9)  
webdriver.ActionChains(browser).click()
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

To move the mouse to an element and then move the mouse 9 pixels up from this element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` to identify the element, move the mouse and finally [*perform()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69963527/actionchains-double-click-method-does-not-performs-the-double-click-using-sele/69963792#69963792) the *action chains* and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "surf-text")))).move_by_offset(0, -9).perform()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: For some reason, the console throws this error:

Traceback (most recent call last)

  File "D:\PythonProjects\AvisoBot\bot.py", line 51, in <module>
    ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "surf-text")))).move_by_offset(0, -9).perform()
  File "C:\Users\brusn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: The error implies the element `(By.CLASS_NAME, "surf-text")` wasn't found. Does the line `classic = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"surf-text")` locates the element?

Comment: on the site, the element from which you need to step back 9 pixels looks like this:
<span class="serf-text">Просмотр видеоролика</span>

Comment: We don't have any clue about either `<span class="serf-text">Просмотр видеоролика</span>` or `By.CLASS_NAME,"surf-text")`. I just have you the syntax to perform the task. Locating the element should be a separate question all together.

Comment: And how to display the cursor in selenium? Or at least to know his position? I need this so that I can configure the bot to work.

Comment: Let me know if [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932569/selenium-keyboard-action-that-will-enable-working-and-testing/61999536#61999536) answers your question in the above comment.

Comment: I didn't find anything in this discussion that could help me. I just need to output the cursor position.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem by using  window.scrollBy
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,1000)","")

the decomention- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy

Comment: This is the best solution. because it does not throw exception it is it outside of view