# Python - Refresh page until Element is clickable

Tags: python, selenium, bots, refresh, element

I'm trying to create this bot that will refresh the page until an element is visible.
My problem is that the bot isn't refreshing and I can't seem to figure out why:)

EDIT: The bot refreshes the desired page now until the desired elememt is visible, however the bot wont click the desired element it was looking for, and that I cant seem to figure out why, since the code says "element.click()"

[I believe that this is the logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFtwt.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")


driver.get("xxx")

driver.maximize_window()


click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="coiPage-1"]/div[2]/div[1]/button[1]')
click.click()

time.sleep(1)

while true:

    if(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="siteContainer"]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/form/button'))
   element.click()
   break
else:
   driver.refresh()
continue
```

Comment: What is element.click()? Also fix the identation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but I will try my best to help you.
First of all, it seems that your indent is wrong, and you forgot a colon after your if condition.
Your `True` need to start with an uppercase to be recognized as a Boolean, and you should use a `try` statement instead of an `if`.

And, you can't click() on a list of WebElement. You need to find **ONE** element, by using `find_element`, not `find_elements`.

If you import `TimeoutException` from `selenium.common.exceptions`, you can use it to determine if an element exist.

```
while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH'//*[@id="siteContainer"]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/form/button')))
        element.click()
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.refresh()
        continue
```

Comment: Why is `try ... except` better than `if`? Would `if` not work or be slower?

Comment: Because Selenium give us tools to catch the exact exception, so why not using them? You should use `try ... except` on every `find_element`, so you can `pass` and print a log if the element don't exist. It can work with `if`, but `try ... except` is prettier in that case.

Comment: Ty Cyanox, your answer worked, now the bot refreshes until element is visible, but it won't click on the desired element:}

Comment: What does the log says?

Comment: You could use `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)` instead of `element.click()` if your element is not clickable at point

Comment: @LunarBurning I've updated my answer, didn't saw the s at elements sooner, sorry

Answer (score 1):

[*`presence_of_element_located()`*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible or clickable/interactable.

Ideally to invoke `click()` on an element you need to you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [***`element_to_be_clickable()`***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) which is the expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it as follows:

```
while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="siteContainer"]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/form/button")))
        element.click()
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.refresh()
        continue
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```