# How can I click the button and move to next page using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am not able to click the button using selenium and move to the next page. I have tried the following commands:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[text()='Production']").click() 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[2]').click
```

I have added a screenshot of the html.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The second line you sent is missing the brackets after .click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on the element with text as ***Production*** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.nav-option.nav-option--main > div.section-title").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='nav-option nav-option--main']/div[@class='section-title']//div[text()='Production']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.nav-option.nav-option--main > div.section-title"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='nav-option nav-option--main']/div[@class='section-title']//div[text()='Production']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 4):

I guess the pagination button is on the bottom of the page, out of the visible screen. If so, to click it you first have to scroll the page down, bring that element into the view and only then click it.
Please try this:

```py
pager = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Production']")))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(0.5)
actions.move_to_element(pager).perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Production']").click()
```