# Python/ Selenium: Clicking an element without id or class attribute

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get a program to click a button using selenium.

I've tried many different `find_elements_by...()` and many different arguments, but I can't figure out which `find_element_by*()`. I need to use and what should be in the argument

Where is what I'm trying to click:

```
<article onclick="mainPrincipalPage.PerformCallback('Registro');">
    <div class="imageBox">
        <img src="../Images/iconRegistroHorario.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="titleBox">
        <span>Registro horario</span>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: What element are you trying to click here?

Answer (score 1):

To click on the *Image Box* within the *`<article>`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "article[onclick^='mainPrincipalPage']>div.imageBox>img").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//article[starts-with(@article, 'mainPrincipalPage')]/div[@class='imageBox']/img").click()
  ```

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "article[onclick^='mainPrincipalPage']>div.imageBox>img"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//article[starts-with(@article, 'mainPrincipalPage')]/div[@class='imageBox']/img"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In order to locate a web element you can use any unique combination of any element attribute values, not only `id` or `CSS Selector`.
For example to locate and click the `article` element you can use this XPath locator:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@onlick,'mainPrincipalPage.PerformCallback(" + "Registro" + ")')]")
```

To click on `span` containing the `Registro horario` text you can simply use

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Registro horario']")
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Selector method to select an element without ID.
All you need to do is seeing the HTML as a folder, with other folders inside. You need to find a tag that you can identify, then find your way to the desired element. This way, you can locate any element, even if another element with the same tag exist.

You can find every CSS selector [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

By the way, you should use By method by importing it: `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'article[onclick="mainPrincipalPage.PerformCallback('Registro');"]').click
```

In your case, without By method, it should look like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector( 'article[onclick="mainPrincipalPage.PerformCallback('Registro');"]').click
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('just copy and paste the Xpath').click()
```

See this picture :
[image: 1]