# How to select this element from this non select drop-down menu using Selenium Webdriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to use Selenium to select the 2nd option (with the text "24 words") from the drop-down menu on this page: https://www.myetherwallet.com/wallet/access/software?type=mnemonic

I was able to click on the drop-down menu to display the 2 options using this piece of code:

```
drop_down_menu = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="v-select__slot"]')
drop_down_menu.click()
```

However I was not able to select the 2nd option (or any options). I could not use Selenium Select class because the drop-down menu element is not of Select type element. I tried the below 2 pieces of code without any success:

```
select_24_words = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#list-item-252-1.v-list-item.v-list-item--link.theme--light'),'24'))
select_24_words.click()
```

and

```
select_24_words = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="list-item-252-1"]')
select_24_words.click()
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Used `element_to_be_clickable` condition for the xpath - `//div[text()='24 words']` and was able to click on `24 word` option.

Try like below once.

```
driver.get("https://www.myetherwallet.com/wallet/access/software?type=mnemonic")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"v-select__selections"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[text()='24 words']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The drop-down menu isn't a conventional [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) element so you can't use *`Select`* class.

To select the 2nd option (with the text "24 words") from the drop-down menu you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.myetherwallet.com/wallet/access/software?type=mnemonic")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='v-select__selections']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='v-list-item__title' and text()='24 words']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: myetherwallet]

- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on the drop-down bar. Then default option.

Then you can click on second option.

All you need is a Explicit Waits.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.myetherwallet.com/wallet/access/software?type=mnemonic")
default_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.v-select__selection--comma")))
default_option.click()

second_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='24 words']/ancestor::div[contains(@id,'item')]")))
second_option.click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```