# How to locate the first channel points button/icon on twitch.tv/esl_csgo using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, twitch

On [twitch.tv/esl_csgo](https://twitch.tv/esl_csgo) I want to click on the channel points button/icon but it keeps giving me the Error
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
I have searched and tried various methods of finding the element for over 4 hours and I have not found a way to click on the element

This is my code but it can not click on the button I want to, help would really be appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
     
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\UserData")
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://twitch.tv/esl_csgo")

time.sleep(10)




element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="c7037441c8fd58e7e0ac6326babcf03d"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/section/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/button/div/div/div/div[2]/span')

element.click()
```

Comment: Try giving full xpath . Also according to new docs its `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'your xpath') `

Comment: Which is that _channel points button/icon_? Are those the _2.3K_?

Comment: I'm not logged in, and I don't see a channel points button, whatever that may be...

Comment: @DebanjanB yes it is

Comment: @httpanand after pasting in the full xpath and using your driver.find_element() method I get this error: 
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/section/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/button/div/div/div/div[2]/span')
NameError: name 'By' is not defined

Comment: By is an import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the *first* channel points button/icon you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='InjectLayout-sc'] > div span[data-test-selector]"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class, 'InjectLayout-sc')]/div//span[@data-test-selector]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```