# How to click on the See all button using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, nosuchelementexception

This script with Selenium in Python 3 helps me to scrape data from a page by clicking the see all button, but it stopped working and I do not know the cause. Could you help me with the code?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

nav= Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver= webdriver.Chrome(service= nav)

driver.get('https://getdaytrends.com/es/venezuela/#moreTrends')
                   
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'btn btn-outline-primary px-5')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", search)

datos= driver.find('table')
```

The Traceback is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn btn-outline-primary px-5"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on <kbd>Ver todo 34</kbd> you need to `scrollIntoView()` the desired element and induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
driver.get("https://getdaytrends.com/es/venezuela/#moreTrends")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='icon icon-longest-lasting']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-outline-primary px-5']"))).click()
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: getdaytrends]

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)