# How to click the second element if the first element is not clickable using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, try-except

How to click the second element if the first element is not clickable using Python Selenium

Code trials:

```
if self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".estimator-container:nth-child(3) .btn").is_not_clicked():
    self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Dont have the Plate?").click();
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML of your page? If possible, you can share the URL too

Comment: this is on python i want to add this commands that when i do the test if  doesnt click this button click another button instead

Comment: Yes, for that, first you need to check, is the button clickable or not, if the result is no, you can click in the another button.

Comment: yes but that i wanted to  know how to writte it in python in selenium

Answer (score 0):

To click on any ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604057/unable-to-locate-element-using-selenium-chrome-webdriver-in-python-selenium/65604613#65604613) wrapping up the the code block within a `try-except{}` block and you can usethe following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".estimator-container:nth-child(3) .btn"))).click()
    print("First element was clicked")
except TimeoutException:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Dont have the Plate?"))).click()
    print("Second element was clicked")
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I want to use the If for that cause after put the fields i press the button it  is disabled cause the input is wrong (i have done this on purpose to select the other button )so i click another button. Does it Make Sense ?

Comment: Are you sure you have got `is_not_clicked()` method/attribute?

Comment: For that i want to ask how i should writte the code only xparh  or od  to work ?

Comment: I have already written the code for you

Comment: Yeah i saw it but i want to use if not try and except method for this. It will help me a lot for this

Comment: _element is not clickable_: A lot depends on what error you see.